# How to write a regex to remove encoded and not encoded words

Tags: php, regex

How to write a regex to remove the encoded and not encoded words from a text.

For example lets assume the following:

```
$string1 = 'do not enter your username';
//The encoded string below is: 'or password';
$string2 = '&#111;&#114 &#112;&#97;&#115;&#115;&#119;&#111;&#114;&#100;';
$string = $string1 . $string2;
```

The regex should remove the not encoded word "username" and encoded words "or password" which after encoding look like this:

```
&#111;&#114 &#112;&#97;&#115;&#115;&#119;&#111;&#114;&#100;
```

I wrote the following regex which works well for not encoded words but fails with encoded.

```
$words_to_remove = 'username|or password';
preg_replace("/\b($words_to_remove)\b/u",  ' ',  $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Speaking more exactly, this `'&#111;&#114 &#112;&#97;&#115;&#115;&#119;&#111;&#114;&#100;'` is a ***numerical HTML encoding*** and should be decoded in more complex way. 
Besides, there's a typo in that encoded string `&#111;&#114 <---`  : `&#114;` is the equivalent for the `r` character, each of such "sequences" should end with a semicolon `;`
The final solution using `html_entity_decode` function should look as below:

```
$string1 = 'do not enter your username ';
$string2 = '&#111;&#114; &#112;&#97;&#115;&#115;&#119;&#111;&#114;&#100;';
$string = html_entity_decode($string1 . $string2);

$words_to_remove = 'username|password';
$string = preg_replace("/($words_to_remove)/u",  ' ',  $string);

print_r($string);
```

The output:

```
do not enter your   or
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm looking for regex that works on strings without  decoding.